# Run-time error during Keras `model.fit` "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_keras_mask'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I start my own image encoder basing on the example from this ["Manipulate complex graph topologies"](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional#manipulate_complex_graph_topologies) (leveraging 2 separate inputs for model). Tensorflow version is 2.2.0

Model compiled successfully (see summary at the end).

My input data looks like following:

```
train_top_reduce, train_left_reduce = ( <list of numpy - 2d matrix>, <list of numpy - 2d matrix>)
train_x = {"top_reduce":train_top_reduce, "left_reduce":train_left_reduce}
train_y = <list of numpy.asarray( PIL's image ) >
```

When I try:

```
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y)
```

I got an exception:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_keras_mask'
>
> c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:571 train_function  *
>           outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
>
> c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
>       return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
>
> c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
>       return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
>
> c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2649 
>   _call_for_each_replica
>       return fn(*args, **kwargs)
>
> c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:531 train_step  **
>       y_pred = self(x, training=True)
>
> c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:927 **call**
>       outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>
> c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py:719 call
>       convert_kwargs_to_constants=base_layer_utils.call_context().saving)
>
> c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py:832 _run_internal_graph
>       input_t._keras_mask = mask

Model summary:

---

Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to

---

top_reduce (InputLayer)         [(None, None, 256, 5 0

---

left_reduce (InputLayer)        [(None, None, 256, 5 0

---

top_dence (Dense)               (None, None, 256, 32 1632        top_reduce[0][0]

---

left_dence (Dense)              (None, None, 256, 32 1632        left_reduce[0][0]

---

concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, None, 256, 64 0           top_dence[0][0]
                                                                 left_dence[0][0]

---

conv2d (Conv2D)                 (None, None, 256, 32 2080        concatenate[0][0]

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After blind search of decision I found that problem was in `<list of numpy - 2d matrix>`. I replaced python list by invoking `numpy.stack(list_of_matrix)` - that converts list to numpy +1 dimension